# PHP: Annotation to multidismentional array

Tags: php, arrays, reflection, annotations

Is there any pretty method to get Annotations from class/method as multidimentional array?
For example I have annotation's like:

```
/**
 * @First
 * @Second({'a'})
 * @Third(subValue:{a: 5})
 */
```

And I want to get sth like:

```
[
            "First" => null,
            "Second" => [
                'a'
            ],
            "Third" => [
                'subValue' => [
                    5
                ]
            ]
 ];
```

Comment: There is [`getdoccomment`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php), but that gets it as a string.

Comment: [doctrine/annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) can do this (Ctrl+F, IndexedReader).

Comment: @Peter Same problem as with annotation reader - requires many unnecesary imports